# python convert string to a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

Assume that you have string x as below:

```
x="['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 'aaa5', 'aaa6', 'aaa7', 'aaa8']"
```

How to convert x to a list of strings in python?

```
['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 'aaa5', 'aaa6', 'aaa7', 'aaa8']
```

Comment: have you tried `eval` with eval(x) ?

Comment: Look at this geeksforgeeks page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-a-string-representation-of-list-into-list/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x="['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 'aaa5', 'aaa6', 'aaa7', 'aaa8']"

type(eval(x)) # list

eval(x)

output : ['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 'aaa5', 'aaa6', 'aaa7', 'aaa8']
```

Comment: eval is a function of which python package?

Comment: its default python package. you can use it for any string to convert it to their suitable datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import ast
list_ = ast.literal_eval(x)
print(list_)
```

output:

```
['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 'aaa5', 'aaa6', 'aaa7', 'aaa8']
```

Comment: Is ast a common package? What does it stand for? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it comes with python. It stands for Abstract Syntax Trees. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html). It is the correct way to handle these types of problems.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this split method

```
y=x.split(,)
```

but it will not split perfectly
first you should remove the bracket and spaces like this

```
x = x.replace('[','')
x = x.repalce(']','')
x = x.replace(' ','')
x = x.replace("'","")
y = x.split(',')
```

this will do yours work

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
x="['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 'aaa5', 'aaa6', 'aaa7', 'aaa8']"

y = eval(x)
```

Here : 
 `x` is `<class 'str'>` 
 `y` is `<class 'list'>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval method. It is simpler!

```
x="['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 'aaa5', 'aaa6', 'aaa7', 'aaa8']"
print(eval(x))
```

Output:
`['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 'aaa5', 'aaa6', 'aaa7', 'aaa8']`